# calling CreateFile, specifying FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY | FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE

Tags: ram, createfile

Before I describe my problem, here is a description of the C++ program I'm writing:

- The purpose of my program is to create file on RAM memory.

I read that if specify `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY | FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` when creating file it will be loaded direct to the RAM memory.

One of blogs that talk about is this one:

> ### [It’s only temporary](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2004/04/19/116084.aspx)
>
> Larry Osterman, April 19, 2004
>
> To create a “temporary” file, you call CreateFile specifying `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY | FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` in the **dwFlagsAndAttributes** attribute.  This combination of bits acts as a hint to the filesystem that the file data should never be flushed to disk.  In other words, such a file can be created, written to, and read from without the system ever touching the disk.

I have built a mini-program, but it doesn't achieve the goal. Instead, it creates a file on the hard-drive, in directory I specify.

Here's my program:

```
void main ()
{
   LPCWSTR str = L"c:\\temp.txt";
   HANDLE fh = CreateFile(str,GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY | FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE,NULL);   

   if (fh == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
      printf ("Could not open TWO.TXT");
      return;
   }

   DWORD dwBytesWritten; 
   for (long i=0; i<20000000; i++)
   {
      WriteFile(fh, "This is a test\r\n", 16, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
   }

   return;
}
```

I think there problem in [**CreateFile**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) function, but I can't fix it. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Larry Osterman also mentions:

> If you exceed available memory, the
>   memory manager will flush the file
>   data to disk. This causes a
>   performance hit, but your operation
>   will succeed instead of failing.

So the OS creates the file in case it needs to flush the data due to memory limits.

Comment: I think it's not the case. I have more than 2GB RAM free.

File I try to create catch few hundreds MB.

Comment: I said "in case." Your program does create the file on my system, so I believe this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The file do be created, on that path you specified.

But that doesn't means windows really write the data to **physical disk**.

All `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` does is tell windows try to cache the file on RAM,
other than that it would just behave like regular file.